# Hidden IE Instance

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file, windows-xp

I'm trying to run internet explorer from a batch script that is launched from the scheduler as system while displaying the window on the active users desktop. The two wrinkles are:
User has no password,
Username is not consistent.

What is the best way to go about this?

I've tried a number of things, and the closest thing I've gotten is:

`PsExec.exe -s -i -l 'C:\path-to-iexplore.exe'`

from a cmd window, which gets me a process that's running as SYSTEM with the GUI shown, but I need the opposite of the -s (system user) flag, or to be able to find and specify -i (current shell.)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yeah, I've been poking at PsExec a lot but I can't figure how to transfer ownership of the process/ etc without some very serious .net or something.


`PsExec.exe -s -i -l 'C:\path-to-iexplore.exe'`

works just fine from console, (eg- process is running as system but is displayed) but no dice from the scheduler.

Comment: Write the closest you've gotten in the question, otherwise you're at risk of down voters.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I was wondering why I got downvoted, though it's obvious now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I succeeded after much trial and error- it seems that for some reason, you've got to call a nested instance of psexec. In my case, it made sense to place the second command in it's own batch file like so:

`C:\path-to-psexec\PsExec.exe -s -i 0 "lock-screen.bat"`

(lock-screen.bat:)
`C:\path-to-psexec\PsExec.exe -s -i 0 -d "C:\path-to-ie\iexplore.exe"`

The -i flag connects to a session, if no session is specified it connects to the current shell's session. If a single user is logged in, it seems that the user's session number is 0. To find out what sessions are active, you may use a second command- [LoginSessions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896769).

I have no idea why I need to run PsExec nested, perhaps someone wiser than myself can explain.